# How can I read multiple arrays with one loop?

Tags: java

For example  I want to multiply array u1 with other array?

```
double[] u1 = {4,2,3,5,3,4};
double[] u2 = {3,0,2,4,2,3};
double[] u3 = {5,0,4,4,4,5};
double[] u4 = {0,1,2,4,2,3};
double[] u5 = {0,3,4,4,4,5};
double[] u6 = {3,1,0,4,2,3};
double[] u7 = {2,5,3,0,3,4};
double[] u8 = {3,1,1,4,2,3};
double[] u9 = {3,1,2,3,2,3};
```

Comment: What attempt have you tried so far? It's not a difficult task if you think about it carefully, and you learning for yourself will teach you far more than an answer here could.

Comment: As the arrays are the same size, it will be safe to loop through them using just one index.

Comment: I want to use one variable for all arrays?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying but you can put your arrays into an array. `double[][] u = { u1, u2, ...`, with that `u[0]` is equvalent to `u1` and `u[0][0]` is `u1[0]`

Comment: It is helpful , thank you

Comment: @Morad, what's helpful? To whom are you speaking?

Comment: What does multiplying one array with another look like? Are we talking cross product? Dot product?

Comment: Mathieu k. I want to do this:  u1*u2 (4*3, 2*0, 3*2, 5*4, 3*2, 4*3)
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
                        u1*u9 (4*3, 2*1, 3*2, 5*3, 3*2, 4*3) in one loop

Comment: Multiplying the arrays and iterating over multiple at once are entirely different problems

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < u1.length; i++)
{
   u1[i] = value;
   u2[i] = value;
   //Etc
}
```

Comment: He *is* reading all the arrays with one loop. It's one **for** loop.

Comment: @Morad, since they're all the same size, one loop will cover them all equally, therefore you can use the same value of `i`

Answer (score 1):

here what I got but is not complete:

```
public class Diff {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double[] u1 = {4,2,3,5,3,4};
    double[] u2 = {3,0,2,4,2,3};
    double[] u3 = {5,0,4,4,4,5};
    double[] u4 = {0,1,2,4,2,3};
    double[] u5 = {0,3,4,4,4,5};
    double[] u6 = {3,1,0,4,2,3};
    double[] u7 = {2,5,3,0,3,4};
    double[] u8 = {3,1,1,4,2,3};
    double[] u9 = {3,1,2,3,2,3};
    double[][] u = {u2,u3};

    for (int k=0; k < u1.length; k++){
    for(int i = 0; i < u.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < u[i].length; j++){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(u1[k]*u[i][j]);
        }

    }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since your arrays are all the same size you can iterate all of them at the same time with only one index, thus, in a simple `for` cicle you can access and manipulate the data in all your arrays at once. In your case, if you want to multiply u1 and u2:

```
   double multiply[] = new double[u1.length];
   for(int i = 0; i < u1.length; i++){
        multiply[i] = u1[i] * u2[i];
   }
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel Almeida and Zapl this is what I'm looking for (^-^). Thank you to all of you....